# Como devuelvo la cantidad de stock disponible de un producto?

Tags: javascript

Estaría necesitando ayuda con un código que no me estaría dando el resultado deseado, lo hice pero me devuelve un numero distinto y no el que quiero.

```
    function checkInventario(inventario, item) {
  // La funcion 'checkInventario' recibe como argumento un array de objetos llamado 'inventario' y el nombre de un item llamado 'item'
  // Cada objeto tiene una propiedad 'nombre' y 'cantidad'.
  // La funcion debe devolver la cantidad de items que hay.
  // Si el item no existe la funcion tiene que devolver 0 (cero).
  // Ej:
  // var inventario = [
  //   {
  //     nombre: 'tenedor',
  //     cantidad: 6
  //   },
  //   {
  //     nombre: 'cuchara',
  //     cantidad: 4,
  //   },
  // ]
  // checkInventario(inventario, 'tenedor') devuelve => 6

  // Tu código aca:
  var haystock = 0;
  for(var i in inventario){
    if(inventario[i].cantidad > 1){
      haystock += inventario[i].cantidad;
    } else {return 0};
  }
  return haystock;
}
```

Lo que yo hago en ese código fue recorrer todo el inventario (productos) en la propiedad de cantidad, si la cantidad es superior a 1, se le suma al stock disponible y si el producto no se encuentra que devuelva 0.

Mi problema es el siguiente: según parece mi código esta bien, solo que al ejecutarlo me devuelve en numero 10, en lugar de por ejemplo: 5 y eso hace que no este viendo el error.

Comment: Bienvenido a StockOverflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour], así aprendes como funciona la plataforma y además ganar tu primer medalla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se da debido a que no estas comprobando que el `nombre` del producto en el arreglo `inventario` coincida con el valor de la variable `item`.

#### Solución:

```js
function checkInventario(inventario, item) {
  let haystock = 0;
  for (var i in inventario) {
    // ACA comprobamos que el nombre sea igual al item indicado
    if (inventario[i].nombre == item) {
      haystock += inventario[i].cantidad;
    }
  }
  return haystock;
}

// Test
let inventario = [{
      nombre: 'tenedor',
      cantidad: 6
    },
    {
      nombre: 'cuchara',
      cantidad: 4,
    },
  ],
  stock = checkInventario(inventario, 'tenedor');
console.log("checkInventario(inventario, 'tenedor') => ", stock);
```

Comment: Gracias crack!!